# Is there an OSM XAPI tag/value list?

Tags: filter, openstreetmap

I'm new to OSM querying, but would like to query vector data for a large area. Thus I need to limit the results I would like to get by tagging the request.

```
http://www.informationfreeway.org/api/0.6/way[tag=value][bbox=x,y,z,j]
```

I'd like to filter for specific tag/values when querying for a way. Though I don't know which tags/values exist. Is there a list listing the most common of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching your problem from the wrong direction. The number of different tags is almost unlimited. According to [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/reports/database_statistics) there are currently 75 380 856 different tags. I'm pretty sure you are not interested in most of them. Likewise you are probably not even interested in many of the most common tags.

What data do you want to query?

The [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) should be your starting point for generating a list of tags you are interested in. For a generic overview take a look at the [map features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features). Are you interested in streets? Then visit at the [highway key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway). Routing? Then take a look at the [routing wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).

Always remember that these lists aren't complete. People can use [any tag they like](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Any_tags_you_like) (but should use well-established tags whenever possible of course).

Also consider using [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) instead of XAPI. Overpass API is much more powerful.